# Dynamic name in for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can I assign dynamic name in loop for

```
Table tbl = new Table();
```

i am trying to make dynamic table in aspx page . but because of static name .it is overriding all the time .please advise ?

Comment: Do you need a `List<Table>`?

Comment: i need when a button funtion hit i need different different name 
Table tbl = new Table();  Table tbl1 like this = new Table();

Answer (score 1):

Add each instance to the Controls collection for the page (or control if you're embedding it) and set the ID to something unique.

```
var names = new string[] { "Table1", "Table2" };
foreach (var name in names)
{
    this.Controls.Add( new Table { ID = name } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a repeater with a template of the information.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/x4s0xktt(v=vs.100)